# Is the word the name of a person or an adjective?

Tags: nouns, adjectives, hebrew

I don't know hebrew and I was reading a transliteration of the following phrase,

"חכו ממתקים וכלו מחמדים זה דודי וזה רעי בנות ירושלם׃"

Is the word "מחמדים" referring to a person name or an adjective ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It's [Song of Solomon 5:16](http://biblehub.com/text/songs/5-16.htm) and the word means "most sweet", so it is not a name. The [New International Version](http://biblehub.com/songs/5-16.htm) of the Bible translates it as

> His mouth is sweetness itself; he is altogether lovely. This is my beloved, this is my friend, daughters of Jerusalem.

Comment: but normally, when the suffix "im" is added to a word, it becomes a plural masculin as far as I read, by why "most sweet" is plural masculine ?

Comment: Dear @user230994 - the apparent plural is just a "majestic plural" in this case and in most of the Bible, to emphasize the respect, but the underlying entity is still singular, see e.g. https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090515023626AAyC6z0

Comment: thanks for your help, as far as I know majestic plural is a word used to refer to a single entity to emphasize respect on that entity, so, why will "im" be added to ""most sweet"" if it refers to a single entity ?